# How to parameterize an ALTER ROLE statement in Postgresql?

Tags: php, postgresql, escaping, postgresql-9.2

I'm trying to make a PHP interface to my PSQL database, and I would like a few local users registered on PSQL to log into my DB. I would first create each username for each user, with a generic password like 'Password123', and then the user could latter change his/her password.

To do that, I thought of using a simple PHP form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr> <td> User: </td> <td> <input type="text" name="user" /> </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> Old password: </td> <td> <input type="password" name="old" /> </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> New password: </td> <td> <input type="password" name="new1" /> </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> Repeat new password: </td> <td> <input type="password" name="new2" /> </td> </tr>
     <tr> <td> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Change password" /> </td> </tr>
</form>

<?php
    if ($_POST) {
        $user = $_POST["user"];
        $old = $_POST["old"];
        $new1 = $_POST["new1"];
        $new2 = $_POST["new2"];

        $link = pg_connect("dbname=mydb host=localhost user=$user password=$old connect_timeout=1");
        if (!$link) { 
            die("Error connecting to mydb: ".pg_last_error($link)); 
        }

        if ($new1 <> $new2) {
            pg_close($link);
            die("New passwords do not match.");
        }

        $res = @pg_query($link,"ALTER ROLE $user WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '$new1';");
        if ($res) {
            echo "Password successfully changed!<br>";
        } else {
            echo "Failed to change password...<br>";
        }

        pg_close($link);
    }
?>
```

It does work just as I expected!

But I read that there are some SQL Injection Attacks that could be made on expressions like this where there is a simple variable interpolation inside the SQL query. And so I read that `PREPARE` statements are the safest way to do such queries. I expected to do something like:

```
pg_prepare($link,"change_user","ALTER ROLE $1 WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '$2';");
```

But I get a syntax error, even if I try to `PREPARE` this command in pgAdminIII. Indeed, [Postgres manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-prepare.html) indicates that `PREPARE` can only prepare "Any SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or VALUES statement."

Then I tried to use the `pg_escape_string()` function:

```
$user = pg_escape_string($_POST["user"]);
...
```

This works well when I use normal passwords, and if I try to set a password like `''"`, I cannot change it afterwards. I have tried `pg_escape_literal` [which is preferred](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-literal.php) to `pg_escape_string` according to the manual, but my PHP is version 5.3.13, and this command is only for 5.4.4 onwards.

The question is: is this the best way to prevent injection attacks in this case? Does this really prevent attacks?

Another question: if a user wants to use an apostrophe in his/her password, is it possible without this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a note, I would recommend using a stored procedure for this.  A prepared statement if needed could always call the stored procedure.

Here's some very simple sample code, largely copied from LedgerSMB (and edited a bit):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save_user(
    in_username text,
    in_password TEXT
) returns bool
SET datestyle = 'ISO, YMD' -- needed due to legacy code regarding datestyles
AS $$
    DECLARE

        stmt text;
        t_is_role bool;
    BEGIN
        -- WARNING TO PROGRAMMERS:  This function runs as the definer and runs
        -- utility statements via EXECUTE.
        -- PLEASE BE VERY CAREFUL ABOUT SQL-INJECTION INSIDE THIS FUNCTION.

       PERFORM rolname FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = in_username;
       t_is_role := found;

       IF t_is_role is true and t_is_user is false and in_pls_import is false THEN
          RAISE EXCEPTION 'Duplicate user';
        END IF;

        if t_is_role and in_password is not null then
                execute 'ALTER USER ' || quote_ident( in_username ) ||
                     ' WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD ' || quote_literal (in_password)
                     || $e$ valid until $e$ ||
                      quote_literal(now() + '1 day'::interval);
        elsif  t_is_role is false THEN
            -- create an actual user
                execute 'CREATE USER ' || quote_ident( in_username ) ||
                     ' WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD ' || quote_literal (in_password)
                     || $e$ valid until $e$ || quote_literal(now() + '1 day'::interval);
       END IF;

       return true;

    END;
$$ language 'plpgsql' SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Note that this is a security definer function.  It is generally recommended that you set this function to be owned by a user which is not a database superuser.  Such a user would need createrole privileges and access to whatever tables you want to manage here.  Also note the warning heavily.  In-db SQL-injection is possible if you don't appropriately escape your parameters.  Note that this function can both create a user and change a password.  The LSMB-specific portions regarding detecting whether the user is set up and handling the case if not are omitted here.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I see there are some undeclared variables in your code, such as `in_pls_import`and `t_is_user`, but I assume that is because you extracted the text from the [admin module in LedgerSMB](https://github.com/jfkw/ledgersmb/blob/master/sql/modules/admin.sql). The idea of making a function `change_password` that executes the query, and then parameterize the query `SELECT change_password(new_password)` is very good, I have not tought of that! But the code warns of SQL injection attacks... If I use a `PREPARE` statment with this function do I get vulnerable?

Comment: you can't prepare a utility statement because it has no query plan (same reason you can't parameterize it).  The code warns about SQL injection because these statements cant be parameterized.

The values come into the function parameterized so it is a matter of making sure they are properly escaped.  The protection is to use `quote_ident()` on identifiers and `quote_literal()` on literal values.  (Yes, the undeclared variables are due to me cutting out the LSMB-specific portions of the logic and not getting it all).

Comment: One final caution:  Since a function is likely to be `SECURITY DEFINER` if you are changing the current user's password make sure you set the password of `SESSION_USER` rather than `CURRENT_USER` since the latter will be set locally in the function to the function's owner!

Comment: I tried to use your idea, and created a function that changes the password of a given user, `PREPARE`d a statement with `SELECT change_pass('user','pass')`, and it worked! It is safely prepared, then? About the `SECURITY DEFINER`, I made my script to change only the role of the user that logs into the DB, so I do not use these variables (`SESSION` and `CURRENT_USER`).

Comment: The problem is that prepare only prepares to the level of "call this function."  The function has to create a SQL string and execute it, and it is there that you have the possibility of SQL injection.  Again ALWAYS use `quote_literal` and `quote_ident`

Comment: I see. So I got the false impression that the parameters were safe in this way... I'm still learning what this `PREPARE` does. As Daniel Verité suggested, I'm now filtering the inputs, so there should be less trouble.

Answer (score 6):

As you found out, prepared statements cannot be used for "utility statements" like `ALTER USER`, they're out of the scope of this question.

The user and the password must be properly quoted, and to do it properly there are several issues to consider.

The user is an **identifier** and the password is a **string literal**, which is why the identifier is not surrounded by single quotes whereas the password is. They do not follow the same syntactic rules and can't be quoted with same functions.

php-5.4.4 provides [`pg_escape_identifier`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-identifier.php) for identifiers but older versions provide nothing to quote identifiers. `pg_escape_string` is not suitable for that, as noted in its description and user comments. PostgreSQL itself provides the `quote_ident` function, but in order to call it, a separate query should be made. Basically this could look like this:

```
$pgr=pg_query_params($dbconn, 'SELECT quote_ident($1)',
                     array(pg_escape_string($_POST["user"])));
// error check on $pgr omitted for brievity
list($quoted_user) = pg_fetch_array($pgr);
$quoted_password = pg_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
$res=pg_query($dbconn, 
              "ALTER USER $quoted_user WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '$quoted_password'");
```

However, you may question whether it's a good idea to let users choose any password they want, without filtering.

Among the problems it causes, one that raises immediately is in your connect call:

```
$link = pg_connect("dbname=mydb host=localhost user=$user password=$old connect_timeout=1");
```

Here the password in `$old` is not quoted and if it contains, say a space character, this is going to fail. This is the likely reason of this problem you mention:  *if I try to set a password like ''", I cannot change it afterwards*.

To handle special characters in the `pg_connect` call, the doc says this:

> Each parameter setting is in the form keyword = value. Spaces around
>   the equal sign are optional. To write an empty value or a value
>   containing spaces, surround it with single quotes, e.g., keyword = 'a
>   value'. Single quotes and backslashes within the value must be escaped
>   with a backslash, i.e., \' and \.

So if you're set on accepting anything, you should provide a function that does this escaping.

Personally, I would forbid these characters in the first place in user-supplied passwords on the grounds that it's a needless source of problems. As well as non US-ASCII characters because of encoding issues.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately, my PHP is 5.3.13, so I would have to update it to use `pg_escape_identifier`. I use WAMP, so I will see if it is possible to update only PHP without breaking WAMP. As to forbid certain character in password, is there a builtin function in PHP that forbids those characters? Or do I have to build this function by using some regexp, searching for other character not in the allowed list?

Comment: @ThalesMG: the piece of code I provide above doesn't need `pg_escape_identifier`. Also for filtering characters, yes, using `preg_match` or similar with a regexp would do the job.

Comment: Indeed, you use the connection to PSQL to quote `$user`. But then the connection was already successful, right? So I cannot use this before the connection. And the password is escaped with the PHP function `pg_escape_string`, is it the same as calling PSQL and return the results of `SELECT quote_literal($password)`? I will try to implement limitation on the password, nevertheless.

Comment: @ThalesMG: For the `ALTER USER` statement alone, an established connection is needed anyway. The additional SELECT just benefits from this connection. Also about `pg_escape_string`: funtionally it's essentially the same than  `SELECT quote_literal(...)` except that in the latter case you'd need to quote the argument of quote_literal, so there would be a chicken and egg problem.