# Asyncpg "Syntax error at or near $1" Error

Tags: python, postgresql, python-asyncio, roles, asyncpg

I am trying to create users for my Postgres database by passing in arguments via `asyncpg` library:

```
await pool.execute(
    "create user $1 with password '$2' noinherit connection limit 1 in role buyers",
    login, 
    password,)
```

However, when I am trying to run the code, I am getting the following error:
`asyncpg.exceptions.PostgresSyntaxError: syntax error at or near "$1"`

I know that I cannot pass in Table or Database names as arguments in `asyncpg`, but I couldn't find any similar info regarding user names or passwords.

Please let me know if this is the case, or maybe I need to format the contents of the `login` and `password` variables in a certain way for it to work?

Comment: Yes, usernames and passwords don't support parameterised queries as well. You'll need to identifier-escape/literal-escape them yourself and interpolate the SQL string.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the answer, could you please explain what do you mean by `identifier-escape/literal-escape` ? If it's a broad topic, I will be glad for some links that would explain it to me, thanks!

Comment: I haven't found this in the docs either, but see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/18897231/1048572

Comment: I mean that a username is an [identifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) and a password is a [string literal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS). Your postgres client library should provide helper functions for escaping them according to the rules.

Comment: @Bergi Alright, I've read some documentation about those 2 functions. Would I need to call `quote_ident()` on `login` and `quote_literal()` on `password`, or just on `login`? Also, would I need to just call those functions after the query, or inside the query? If I need to call it inside, would I just make it like this: `"create user quote_ident($1) with password quote_literal($2) noinherit connection limit 1 in role buyers"`, or I would need to do something else to make it work? Appreciate all the help!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't mean to say that you should use those two SQL functions to build a dynamic query and `EXECUTE` that in pl/pgsql. Rather try finding python equivalents for those functions. I couldn't find any for asyncpg, but for example [psycopg offers `Literal` and `Identifier`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html).